# Maximum and minimum for 10 numbers in a Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a tableau
for i in `seq 0 9`
do 
    echo "enter a number: "
    read ${tableau[$i]}
done
let "max = ${tableau[0]}"
for j in `seq 1 9`
    if [ ${tableau[$i]} -gt $max ]
    then
        let "max = ${tableau[$i]}"
    fi 
done
echo "Max is: $max"
```

---

The user will enter 10 numbers in a TABLE. I should find the maximum and the minimum from these 10 numbers.

Comment: You're missing `do` in the second `for` loop. Paste your code into shellcheck.net.

Comment: Run it though shellcheck as a first step. Then describe what it's doing that it shouldn't be...

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As said previously, the read statement should not have $ nor {}.
2. There should not have space for variable assignment : max=${tableau[0]}
3. In your second loop you are iterating j but use i for the array index.

That gives

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a tableau

for i in $(seq 0 9); do
    echo "enter a nbr : "
    read tableau[$i]
done
max=${tableau[0]}
for j in $(seq 1 9); do
    if [ ${tableau[$j]} -gt $max ]; then
        max=${tableau[$j]}
    fi
done
echo "Max is : $max"
```

Comment: I wouldn't use let in the assignments in this particular case (the same as you) but the question used let, which is not a wrong thing to do is it?

Comment: Not really, but would still need to get rid of the space : let x=2 not let x = 2.

Comment: spaces around `=` are OK in an arithmetic expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a tableau

for i in `seq 0 9`
do
echo "enter a number: "
  read tableau[$i]
done

max=${tableau[0]}

for j in `seq 1 9`
do          # You missed "do" here!!!!
if [ ${tableau[$j]} -gt $max ]
then
  max=${tableau[$j]}
fi
done

echo "Max is: $max"
```

Output:

```
enter a number:
33
enter a number:
1
enter a number:
3
enter a number:
4
enter a number:
5
enter a number:
6
enter a number:
7
enter a number:
8
enter a number:
9
enter a number:
3
Max is: 33
```

Comment: Your second assignment should not have space : max=${tableau[$j]}

Comment: i've got a proper output on my computer.  
you see an error on yours?

Comment: you missed "do" after the second "for"

Comment: you welcome) . don't forget to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a code review. This is a more Bash-specific way to write it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a tableau
for i in {0..9}; do
    read -p "enter a nbr : " tableau[i]
done

max=${tableau[0]}
for tabl in "${tableau[@]}"; do
    (( tabl > max )) && max=$tabl
done

echo "Max is : $max"
```

Where:

- `read -p` to provide the prompt
- the brace expression instead of calling out to seq
- iterating over the *elements* of the array, not the keys.
- `$` is not strictly required in arithmetic expressions (including for indexed array elements, the code between `[` and `]`)
- use of the `((...))` arithmetic conditional
- the logical `&&` operator

However, you don't even need two loops:

```sh
for i in {0..9}; do
    read -p "enter a nbr : " tableau[i]
    if ((i == 0)) || ((tableau[i] > max)); then
        max=${tableau[i]}
    fi
done
```